# How to fix the error while saving list of custom data types in room database

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to save a list of custom data types in room database, actually, I want one of the column should contain list of all transactions show that I don't have to two tables.

**account.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "account_table")
data class account(

    @ColumnInfo(name="name")
    val name:String,


    @ColumnInfo(name="transaction")

    val transactions:List<transaction>

){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)@ColumnInfo(name="account_id")
    val accountId:Int=0
}
```

**transaction.kt**

```
data class transaction(
    val amount:Float,
    val description:String,
    val date:String

)
```

Now when I am running the code I get an error

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<com.example.ledger.Database.transaction> transactions = null;

                                                                          ^D:\flutterProjects\Ledger\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\ledger\Database\account.java:10: error: Cannot find setter for field.

    private final int accountId = 0;

D:\flutterProjects\Ledger\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\ledger\Database\accountsDao.java:19: warning: The query returns some columns [account_id, name, transaction] which are not used by com.example.ledger.Database.transaction. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. com.example.ledger.Database.transaction has some fields [amount, description, date] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: account_id, name, transaction. Fields in com.example.ledger.Database.transaction: amount, description, date.

    public abstract java.util.List<com.example.ledger.Database.transaction> getTransaction(int id);

                      ^D:\flutterProjects\Ledger\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\ledger\Database\accountsDao.java:19: error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [amount,description,date] in com.example.ledger.Database.transaction even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [account_id,name,transaction]

    public abstract java.util.List<com.example.ledger.Database.transaction> getTransaction(int id);

                                                                            ^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

**EDIT**

**accountDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface accountsDao {
    @Insert
    fun Insert(account: account)

    @Delete
    fun delete(account: account)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_table where account_id = :id ")
    fun getTransaction(id:Int):List<transaction>

}
```

**accountDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [account::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)

abstract class accountsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val accountdao: accountsDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: accountsDatabase? = null


        fun getInstance(context: Context): accountsDatabase? {

            synchronized(this) {
                // Copy the current value of INSTANCE to a local variable so Kotlin can smart cast.
                // Smart cast is only available to local variables.
                var instance = INSTANCE
                // If instance is `null` make a new database instance.
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        accountsDatabase::class.java,
                        "saccount_history_database"
                    )

                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                    // Assign INSTANCE to the newly created database.
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                // Return instance; smart cast to be non-null.
                return instance
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I feel there would some code of type convertor in `Dao` file because I am accessing  `List<transaction>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, lists, models, model list etc. When you want to store some special type objects, such as in the database, you can use Type Converters. Converts your custom object type to a type known for database types. This is the most useful feature of the Room persistent library.

**account.kt:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "account_table")
data class account(

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)@ColumnInfo(name="account_id")
val accountId:Int=0,

@ColumnInfo(name="name")
val name:String,

@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@ColumnInfo(name="transaction")
val transactions:List<transaction>

)
```

**Converters.kt:**

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTransactionList(transaction: List<transaction?>?): String? {
        if (transaction == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<transaction?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(transaction, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTransactionList(transactionString: String?): List<transaction>? {
        if (transactionString == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type =
            object : TypeToken<List<transaction?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<List<transaction>>(transactionString, type)
    }

}
```

You can add like this:

```
@Database(entities = [account::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class accountsDatabase : RoomDatabase()
```

And interface accountsDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM account_table where account_id = :id ")
fun getTransaction(id:Int):List<account>
```

using:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
   val db = accountsDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
   val accounts = db.accountDao().getTransaction(your_id)
   val transactions = accounts[position].transactions
   transactions?.forEach {
            Log.d("Transaction Description" ,it.description)
        }
}
```

Comment: I have added the code but still, there is an error `error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<com.example.ledger.Database.transaction> transactions = null;`

Comment: I have edited the question please check out @Kasım Özdemir

Comment: must be fun getTransaction(id:Int):List<account>

Comment: I have already added typeConverter top of @ColumnInfo(name="transaction"). If you want you can add top of line "abstract class accountsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {" again

Comment: The code is red underlined and it is showing  ` The annotation is not applicable to target value parameter`  and `Too many arguments for public constructor TypeConvertor() defined androids.room.TypeConvertor`

Comment: Can you change name of Converters.kt to another name. As like TransactionConverters.kt

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry I got the problem I used to type `@TypeConvertor` where it should be `@TypeConvertors` .

Comment: I have doubt as I said in of the comments that in `accountsDao` file I want to get all transaction for a particular `accountId` now should since I am returning the list of accounts so how do I access the list of transaction, imagining I am calling `getTransaction` from my view model class. I have changed the function `getTransaction` to fun `getTransaction(id:Int):List<account>`

Comment: val accounts =  db. accountsDao().getTransaction(your_id). -> val transactions = list[position].transactions

Comment: You can do it like this

Comment: Could please give it in answer section it is not clear here

Comment: I edited my answer again. There may mistakes. You fix it.

Comment: Whats TypeToken?

Answer (score -2):

Long story short: you should add a new table. Room is specifically built for you to use a separate table here, you are sacrificing performance and readability to do it this way. Instead, you should define:

```
@Entity(
    ForeignKey(
        parentColumns = ["account_id"],
        entityColumns = ["account_id"],
        entity = Account::class,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, // if you delete the account, transactions are 
                                       //deleted as well
        // you can add an onUpdate cascade, but you shouldn't update account numbers at 
        //all in my opinion      
        
    ) // you'll also want add indexes on (accountId, transactionId), (accountId, date) as well
)
data class Transaction(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val transactionId : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name="account_id")
    val accountId : Int,
    val amount:Float,
    val description:String,
    val date:String
)
```

Now under account you simply add:

```
@Entity(tableName = "account_table")
data class account(

    @ColumnInfo(name="name")
    val name:String,


    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "account_id", 
        entity_column="account_id", 
        entity=Transaction:class
    )
    val transactions:List<Transaction>

){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)@ColumnInfo(name="account_id")
    val accountId:Int=0
}
```